# Installing Fedora with windows 8

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I have a laptop with windows 8 and I installed Ubuntu and it is now dual booted. 
I want to replace the Ubuntu with fedora.

When creating the partitioning the fedora gives me error : For a UEFI installation, you must include an EFI System Partition on a GPT-formatted disk, mounted at /boot/efi.

And hence not able to install the same.

Answer (score 2):

According to [fedora's wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#GPT_and_MBR_disks) :

> If you are doing a UEFI-native installation and using custom partitioning, though, be aware that you must include an EFI system partition mounted at /boot/efi as a part of your partition layout.

In the installer, go for custom partitioning. It'll show you the existing partitions on your disk.

- setup the efi partition: it'll be a small one, around 100Mb in size. Set its mount point to `/boot/efi` (do **not** format it !).
- setup the fedora partition: select your existing linux partition (it'll be ext3 or ext4) and set its mount point to `/`. Format it to wipe out the ubuntu install (backup your files first if there's anything you want to keep!)

That should allow the installer to proceed.
Good luck !